# Gnome shell hot corner not working

Tags: gnome, command-line

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 in Virtual Box (windows XP host).

So far I have:

- Installed the gnome-shell
- Purged the gnome-accessibility-themes
- Installed the gnome-standard-themes
- used gnome-tweak-tool to select the correct window themes etc.

Everything seems to work except the "Hot Corner" i.e. when you move the mouse to the corner of the activities corner there used to be a ripple effect (At least in Fedora 15 when I first tested gnome-shell).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved it:**

My set-up (host) has dual monitors (Laptop + external LCD) :

- Laptop monitor is 1920 x 1200
- LCD is 1280 x 1024

When running in **Full screen** the "Hot Corner" works (*however the top bar is gets messed up*).

In windows mode (*virtual box*) the hot corner does not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to *mouse integration* (that get enabled by default after having installed guest additions).

If you disable mouse integration from Machine menu, hot corners will start to behave correctly, otherwise Virtualbox will kick-in and the corner inside the guest is never really triggered.

Answer (score 0):

My first note is "in Virtual Box". I'm not saying that this is definitely the reason, but it could be. I have tested GNOME Shell on 11.10 and it seems to work normally for me.

You may need to install [dconf-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dconf-editor) [image: Install dconf-tools] and run `dconf-editor`, then try editing GNOME Shell's settings.